# How to configure Rails caching to namespace cache keys with the environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I'm deploying a Rails 6.1 App on a server that hosts both my staging and my production environments, and has a unique memcached instance.

If I don't namespace all cache keys, I believe the same keys will be generated in production and staging. Tests on my staging environment will impact production.

I know I could pass a namespace for each call:

```rb
Rails.cache.write("some-key", "some-value", namespace: Rails.env)
```

But it's error-prone.

I'm looking for a global config saying that **all keys should be namespaced with the environment**.

Comment: Why is your staging and production sharing a memcached instance?

Comment: I only have a single dedicated server, where I deploy both my production and staging instances.

Comment: You can still run multiple instances of memcached on different ports.

Comment: True indeed. I chose the "dev" solution with the namespace, so I don't spend time on the server configuring tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the global config into config/environments/{yourenvironment}.rb as following:

```
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, {namespace: 'yourenvironment-...' }
```

Comment: I ended up doing:

    config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, { namespace: "#{Rails.env}/" }

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it like this using string interpolation.

```
Rails.cache.write("#{Rails.env}-some-key", "some-value")
```

The best is to always use separate caching instance for staging and production environments.